# no output when node.js calls applescript application

Tags: node.js, applescript, nwjs

I'm executing an Applescript application using NodeJS like this:

```
var child = require('child_process').exec('open myApp.app'); 

        child.on('exit', function (code) {
          console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
        });
        child.stdout.on('end', function (data) {
          console.log('end: ' + data);
        });
        child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
          console.log('stdout: ' + data);
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
          console.log('stderr: ' + data);
        });
```

Applescript:

```
tell application "Final Cut Pro" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "2" using command down
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Final Cut Pro"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "File"
                tell menu "File"
                    tell menu item "Export XML..."
                        click
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        tell its front window
            click button "Save"
            click button "Replace" of sheet 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The node code is executed from a node-webkit (nwjs) app. The Applescript app works when ran in ScriptEditor and also when called from the nwjs app.

I'm not getting anything back in the last two event handlers. The first two respectively output:

```
undefined 
0
```

Forcing an error by deliberately writing erroneous Applescript code doesn't result in any output in the node.js error event handler. My question is: how can I get output back from the Applescript into the event handlers? Changing the following order or commenting out the first two doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use node-applescript. 
First install it with npm: `$ npm install applescript` 
Then in your JS file add the code below to run your script.

```
var applescript = require('applescript');


var script = 'tell application "iTunes" to get name of selection'; //you can copy and past your apple script here

applescript.execString(script, function(err, rtn) {
  if (err) {
    // Something went wrong!
  }
  if (Array.isArray(rtn)) {
    rtn.forEach(function(songName) {
      console.log(songName);
    });
  }
});
```

node-applescript docs: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-applescript

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried that module and also node-applescript before but takes 10 to 15 secs or more before the script is fully executed the first time I call it, not sure why. Putting it in an applescript app is much faster, the whole process takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: I meant [node-osascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-osascript) as the other one i tried.

Comment: Ok, I am not exactly sure what the problem is then : \ sorry. Also you might try node-applescript, If you havent yet.